# dependencies in the wrong place with yarn

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, yarnpkg

When I do `yarn install && yarn workspace frontend install && yarn workspace backend install` in my Typescript project (various `package.json` files below) the dependencies for (e.g.) Angular and CDK are all in the root `node_modules` folder, but when I run (e.g.) `yarn workspace frontend ng build`, I get `An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/work/frontend/node_modules/@angular'`. How do I get the dependencies in the right place?

Root `package.json`:

```
  "name": "load-tester",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "backend",
    "frontend"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "yarn workspace frontend ng build && yarn workspace backend deploy"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-ec2": "^3.34.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-elastic-load-balancing-v2": "^3.34.0",
    "@middy/http-content-negotiation": "^2.5.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.12.28"
  }
}
```

`frontend/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-sns": "^3.34.0",
    "@okta/okta-angular": "^4.1.0",
    "@okta/okta-auth-js": "^5.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

`backend/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk",
    "deploy": "yarn build && yarn cdk deploy"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/assert": "^1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-certificatemanager": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs": "^1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs-patterns": "^1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-logs": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-s3-deployment": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sqs": "^1.121.0",
    "@aws-solutions-constructs/aws-cloudfront-s3": "1.121.0",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.83",
    "@types/http-errors": "^1.8.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.9.6",
    "@types/source-map-support": "^0.5.4",
    "aws-cdk": "^1.121.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.0",
    "json-schema-to-ts": "^1.6.4",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers": "^1.130.0",
    "@aws-cdk/cloud-assembly-schema": "^1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "^1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/cx-api": "^1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/region-info": "^1.121.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.34.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-ecs": "^3.34.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-elastic-load-balancing-v2": "^3.34.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-route-53": "^3.34.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.34.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-sqs": "^3.34.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.34.0",
    "@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt": "^3.34.0",
    "@dazn/lambda-powertools-logger": "^1.28.1",
    "@dazn/lambda-powertools-pattern-basic": "^1.29.0",
    "@middy/core": "^2.5.1",
    "@middy/http-cors": "^2.5.1",
    "@middy/http-error-handler": "^2.5.1",
    "@middy/http-json-body-parser": "^2.5.1",
    "@middy/http-multipart-body-parser": "^2.5.1",
    "@middy/sqs-json-body-parser": "^2.5.1",
    "@middy/validator": "^2.5.1",
    "@okta/jwt-verifier": "^2.3.0",
    "ajv": "^8.6.3",
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.6",
    "constructs": "^3.2.0",
    "exponential-backoff": "^3.1.0",
    "http-errors": "^1.8.0",
    "middy-jsonapi": "2.0.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to have been my `angular.json`; in particular anywhere referring to `./node_modules/@angular`. When I changed that to `../node_modules/@angular` I was able to successfully build both frontend and backend.